# OPENSSL How to store and recover keys to encrypt and decrypt messages?

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

This is what i know:

Generate RSA Public & Private Key

```
RSA *pRSA      = NULL;
EVP_PKEY* pKey = NULL;
pRSA = RSA_generate_key(2048,RSA_3,gen_callback,NULL);
pKey = EVP_PKEY_new();
if(pRSA && pKey && EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pKey,pRSA))
{
    /* pKey owns pRSA from now */
    if(RSA_check_key(pRSA) <= 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"RSA_check_key failed.\n");
        EVP_PKEY_free(pKey);
        pKey = NULL;
    }
}
```

Convert key(EVP_KEY) to unsigned char so that i can store into a file.

Note: i do know how to write and read to/from PEM file, however i would like to implement it such a way that i can save the key into my own file formats for many other reasons.

```
//Convert to public key

int pkeyLen;
unsigned char *ucBuf, *uctempBuf;
pkeyLen = i2d_PublicKey(pKey, NULL);
ucBuf = (unsigned char *)malloc(pkeyLen+1);
uctempBuf = ucBuf;
i2d_PublicKey(pKey, &uctempBuf);

//Convert to Private Key

int pkeyLen2;
unsigned char *ucBuf2, *uctempBuf2;
pkeyLen2 = i2d_PrivateKey(pKey, NULL);
ucBuf2 = (unsigned char *)malloc(pkeyLen2+1);
uctempBuf2 = ucBuf2;
i2d_PrivateKey(pKey, &uctempBuf2);
```

Encrypt Message using RSA

```
(encrypt_len2 = RSA_public_encrypt(strlen(msg),msg,(unsigned char*)encrypt2,pRSA, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING)
```

I do know how to convert unsigned char back to EVP using:
   d2i_PublicKey & d2i_PrivateKey

**However this is what i do not know and is hoping someone does:**

How do i convert my EVP_KEY (public & private) back to the RSA structure

(Example: RSA *pRSA which is returned after using RSA_generate_key)?

Comment: If you want the specific pieces of the RSA key structures, is there some reason you don't convert them to a known format (for example an ASN.1 RSAPublicKey for the public key), then pull the big-integer bytes out and store them however you want. You can always reassemble them back. OpenSSL has all the appropriate code libraries to do this (DER format would be my choice, as it is the easiest to pull the raw big-integer bytes from, imho).

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Thanks Alex! made the appropriate changes.

Comment: @WhozCraig PEM file format already is ASN.1 DER format, although it is base 64 encoded and prefixed/postfixed with PEM specific header/footer. Why you would want to do your own DER is beyond me. Using the BigIntegers directly could safe some space, although you should be able to calculate the right sizes somehow.

Comment: null, what kind of format *do* you want to store your keys in, if not PEM?

Comment: @owlstead I never said anything about doing  "my own DER". I said I would prefer DER as the interceding format between my code and the OpenSSL API simply because it is one hop from the raw bytes. If you (the OP) want to store the modulus and exp of a public key in your own private Idaho, pulling them from a DER is direct, requires no b64-decode, and has already solved your "able to calculate the right sizes somehow" problem. The reverse trip is equally true, but in short it is all because the format is supported by the API (as is PEM, but I don;t like the extra b64 steps).

Comment: @WhozCraig oh, I voted up the comment, it is more a comment toward null; the method of encoding to DER should already be present in openssl, so why you would want to first go to a big integer and encode those values is beyond me (or the other way around for that matter)

Comment: @owlstead ok, totally my bad then, sir. sorry. That the format is provided and so close to the bits he wants is the reason I would use it, but like you, I honestly don't understand why not just use that format in the first place. It provides what you need unless your intention is to somehow obfuscate your bits, which could equally be done with a DER anyway (or all the way to PEM). So yeah, I agree. Why reinvent the wheel in the first place.

Comment: hi all, i can store in any format actually. i just want to convert it to unsigned char so i can store it in a config file.. i am able to convert to EVP & unsigned char. However when i do not know how to use the EVP or unsigned char to declare RSA structure such that i can encrypt & decrypt data.

Comment: i am now looking into BIO, but still am not sure how to use it. would appreciate if anyone can give answers. been doing this for quite awhile.. :(

Comment: @owlstead able to point me in the right direction for using PEM to encrypt and decrypt data? :)

Comment: Maybe you can look for functionality such as `EVP_PKCS82PKEY()`. Problem is that openssl contains a lot of functionality that is not documented at all. It took me 5 minutes just to find this function call :( . If really cannot find the functionality you could retrieve and parse the PEM format from memory to get to the wrapped DER format. Or you could re-encode the binary PEM format in yet another format (that's a bit extreme though)

Comment: @owlstead haha. thanks! this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution to my problem. Hopefully this will help those that face the same problem as me.

```
char *ct = "This the clear text";
unsigned char *buf;   
unsigned char *buf2;
int lenss;
/* No error checking */
    buf =(unsigned char*) malloc(EVP_PKEY_size(rsaPubKey));
    buf2 =(unsigned char*) malloc(EVP_PKEY_size(rsaPubKey));

lenss = RSA_public_encrypt(strlen(ct)+1,(unsigned char*) ct, buf, rsaPubKey->pkey.rsa,RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);

if (lenss != EVP_PKEY_size(rsaPubKey))
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: ciphertext should match length of key\n");
    exit(1);
}

RSA_private_decrypt(lenss, buf, buf2, rsaPrivKey->pkey.rsa,RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);

printf("%s\n", buf2);
```

found my solution through one of the code in the openssl example directory. :)

Comment: Thanks for the code but how does this help you store / retrieve the keys?

Comment: @owlstead as in my question, you can convert the key to unsigned char. after which you can store etc. When you want to use it as a key, convert it back to EVP & you can use it by rsaPubKey->pkey.rsa